# Yii2 Upload video file return error 400

Tags: file-upload, yii2

I use Yii2 and want to upload video file .. with images i do not have problems, but when i try to upload video it is return error 400 ... i read two similar question like mine, but they have not answers ... if i miss something?
view:

```
   $childVideo = array();
       $model->getErrors();

       $count = 0;
       if(isset($modelVideo) and $modelVideo->hasVideo()){
           $count = 1;
           $childVideo = $model->getKartikPhotos();
       }else{
           echo '<img src="/images/video.jpg" style="width: 15%" />';
       }
       echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">';
       echo $form->field($model, 'videoFiles[]')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
           'options' => [
               'multiple' => true,
               'disabled' => ((Yii::$app->params['numberUserVideo'] - $count) == 0) ? true : false,
           ],
           'pluginOptions' => [
               'fileActionSettings' => [
                   'removeIcon' => '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i> ',
               ],
               'initialPreview' => $childVideo,
               'showRemove' => false,
               'showUpload' => false,
               'allowedFileExtensions' => Yii::$app->params['allowedUserVideoExtensions'],
               'maxFileCount' => Yii::$app->params['numberUserVideo'] - $count,
           ],
       ]);
       echo '</div>';
```

and in controller when i try to var_dump($_POST) it is show error 400 ...

Comment: The reason could be the size of your video file. How much are set the **upload_max_filesize  and  post_max_size** values on your server? Are you using a local server (Xampp, Wamp, ...) ?

Comment: now i check and the upload_max_size is only 8M , how can to override it to 512M ? i cant see php.ini file

Comment: did it really fixed by changing the values in `php.ini` , does it show you the `400` error if you upload a file with a smaller size that is valid according tot he current setings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the values of the upload_max_filesize & post_max_size variables in php.ini config file.

> ; Maximum allowed size upload_max_filesize = 100M
>
> ; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize post_max_size =
>   100M

Use a common sense value for the uploads.

After modifying php.ini file(s), restart your server to use new configuration.

If you have a hosted system you will need to ask your host service to increase the values.